# Can't use ref to select swiper methods

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, swiper.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to invoke .slideNext() & .slidePrev that come with swiper when the user presses the arrow keys.

I've managed to do this with querySelector like this:

```js
const changeSlide = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {

    const slides = document.querySelector('.swiper').swiper

    if(event.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      slides.slidePrev();
    } else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      slides.slideNext();
    }

}
```

However this method creates warnings and the usage of querySelector is not allowed in general for this project. So instead i wan't to use a ref to select the swiper but i've not yet succeeded at this.

This is what i tried:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue';
import { Navigation } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
// just some imports that are needed

const swiperRef = ref();
// swiper as ref

const changeSlide = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {

    const slides = swiperRef.value.swiper
    // instead of querySelector i use the ref.value

    if(event.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      slides.slidePrev();
    } else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      slides.slideNext();
    }

}
</script>

<template>
<swiper
  ref="swiperRef"
  :initial-slide="props.initialSlide"
  :slides-per-view="1"
  :space-between="0"
  :modules="[Navigation]"
  navigation
>
  <swiper-slide>  // left out the attributes since they are a mere distraction
    <img/> // left out the attributes since they are a mere distraction
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper>
</template>
```

The error i get from this code is:
[image]

Comment: What do you have in the `swiperRef.value` object? Doesn't this have the `slideNext` method already, without going for `.swiper`?

Comment: If i try that i get `Uncaught TypeError: swiperRef.value.slidePrev is not a function`, But it is indeed the case that swiperRef.value.swiper returns `undefined`. While swiperRef.value returns an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I'm seeing in [the source code](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/src/vue/swiper.js#L351), you can't access the `swiper` instance using `ref` on the `swiper` vue component because it's not exposed.

You have others way to do thought:

- inside a child component of the `<swiper>` component, use the `useSwiper()` component.
- on the parent component that instanciate the `<swiper>` component, use the `@swiper` event. It sends the `swiper` object once mounted:

```html
<template>
 <swiper @swiper="getRef" />
</template>

<script setup>
const swiper = ref(null)
function getRef (swiperInstance) {
  swiper.value = swiperInstance
}

function next () {
  swiper.value.slideNext() // should work
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use this method instead you can just import `Keyboard` like this:

```js
import { Navigation } from 'swiper';
```

Add Keyboard to modules and attributes of `<swiper>` like this:

```js
<swiper :modules="[Navigation, Keyboard]" keyboard />
```

And add the attribute to `<swiper-slide>` as well:

```js
<swiper-slide keyboard />
```